# Delete entire row if cell (date) value is within the time range

Tags: excel, vba

I need help on my coding. So basically the codes below will get the data from another sheet and close it automatically. What I wanted to output is just the rows that will fall between 14:00 and 22:00 of the day. So if the SLA target date would be beyond that range, I'l like to delete that row and shift up so that the output will have no spaces in between. I'm not sure how to do it.

below is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call ClearData
    Call ReadDataFromCloseFile
End Sub


Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim src_im As Workbook
    Dim src_fr As Workbook
    Dim src_chm As Workbook
    ' OPEN THE SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK IN "READ ONLY MODE".
    Set src_im = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\incident_sla.csv", True, True)
    ' GET THE TOTAL ROWS FROM THE SOURCE WORKBOOK.
    Dim iTotalRows_im As Integer
    iTotalRows_im = src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set src_fr = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sc_req_item_sla.csv", True, True)
    Dim iTotalRows_fr As Integer
    iTotalRows_fr = src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set src_chm = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\change_task.csv", True, True)
    Dim iTotalRows_chm As Integer
    iTotalRows_chm = src_chm.Worksheets("change_task").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    ' COPY DATA FROM SOURCE (CLOSE WORKGROUP) TO THE DESTINATION WORKBOOK.
    Dim iCnt_im As Integer         ' COUNTER.
    For iCnt_im = 2 To iTotalRows_im
    If Format(src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("G" & iCnt_im).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm") < Format(Date + TimeValue("22:00:00"), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm") Then
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("A" & iCnt_im).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("B" & iCnt_im).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_im + 2).WrapText = False
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("C" & iCnt_im).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_im + 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_im + 2).Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("D" & iCnt_im).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("E" & iCnt_im).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("F" & iCnt_im).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("G" & iCnt_im + 2).Value = Format(src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("G" & iCnt_im).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("H" & iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("H" & iCnt_im).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("H" & iCnt_im + 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("H" & iCnt_im + 2).Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("I" & iCnt_im + 2).Value = Format(Date + TimeValue("22:00:00"), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("J" & iCnt_im + 2).Formula = Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("I" & iCnt_im + 2).Value <= Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("G" & iCnt_im + 2).Value
    Else
            Worksheets("Pre-shift").Rows(iCnt_im + 2).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
    Next iCnt_im

    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A3") = "Incident ID"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A3").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B3") = "Title"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B3").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C3") = "Assignee Name"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C3").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D3") = "Status"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D3").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E3") = "Service Type"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E3").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F3") = "Priority"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F3").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("G3") = "SLA Target Date"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("G3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("G3").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("H3") = iCnt_im
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("H3").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("H3").Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'
'    Dim after As Integer
'
'    For after = 2 To iCnt_im
'    If Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("J" & after + 2).Value = False Then
'    Else
'            Worksheets("Pre-shift").Rows(after + 2).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
'    End If
'    Next after

'    If iCnt_im = 2 Then
'    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A4").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)
'    End If
    Dim iCnt_fr As Integer
    For iCnt_fr = 2 To iTotalRows_fr
'        If CDate(src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").Range("E" & iCnt_fr).Formula) > Now() Then
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").Range("A" & iCnt_fr).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").Range("B" & iCnt_fr).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).WrapText = False
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").Range("C" & iCnt_fr).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").Range("D" & iCnt_fr).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").Range("E" & iCnt_fr).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").Range("F" & iCnt_fr).Formula
        Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("G" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_fr.Worksheets("sc_req_item_sla").Range("G" & iCnt_im).Formula
'        Else: .EntireRow.Delete
'        End If
    Next iCnt_fr
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Fulfillment ID"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Title"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Assignee Name"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Status"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "SLA Target Date"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Assignment"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    Dim iCnt_chm As Integer
    For iCnt_chm = 2 To iTotalRows_chm
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_chm.Worksheets("change_task").Range("A" & iCnt_chm).Formula
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_chm.Worksheets("change_task").Range("B" & iCnt_chm).Formula
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_chm.Worksheets("change_task").Range("C" & iCnt_chm).Formula
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    'Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).WrapText = True
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_chm.Worksheets("change_task").Range("D" & iCnt_chm).Formula
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_chm.Worksheets("change_task").Range("E" & iCnt_chm).Formula
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_chm.Worksheets("change_task").Range("F" & iCnt_chm).Formula
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Borders.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Worksheets("Pre-shift").Range("G" & iCnt_chm + iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 2).Formula = src_chm.Worksheets("change_task").Range("G" & iCnt_chm).Formula

    Next iCnt_chm
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Parent Change"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Task ID"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Title"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Assignee"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Status"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Planned Start"
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("G" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Formula = "Planned End"

    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("A" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("B" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("C" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("D" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("E" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("F" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("G" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Sheets("Pre-shift").Range("G" & iCnt_fr + iCnt_im + 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

    ' CLOSE THE SOURCE FILE.
    src_im.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set src_im = Nothing
    src_fr.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set src_fr = Nothing
    src_chm.Close False             ' FALSE - DON'T SAVE THE SOURCE FILE.
    Set src_chm = Nothing

ErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will correctly evaluate your time values.  Can't you just not COPY DATA FROM SOURCE (CLOSE WORKGROUP) TO THE DESTINATION WORKBOOK?

For it to be today's date, just check that too

```
If TimeValue(src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("G" & iCnt_im).Value) > TimeValue("13:59:59") And TimeValue(src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("G" & iCnt_im).Value) < TimeValue("22:00:01")  and Int(src_im.Worksheets("incident_sla").Range("G" & iCnt_im).Value) = Date Then
```

Comment: This would have a problem if the source data is between more than a day (e.g 3 days)

Comment: Are you saying there is a date to the criteria?  What date are you checking?

Comment: Yes. I only wanted to get the data between 14:00 - 22:00 of the date today.